# Simple threading question, locking non local changes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, critical-section

Ok first I must preface this question with a disclaimer, I'm really new to threading so this may be a 'newbie' question but I searched google and couldn't find an answer. As I understand it a critical section is code that can be accessed by two or more threads, the danger being one thread will overwrite a value before the other is finished and vice versa. What can you do about changes made outside of your class for example, I have a line monitoring program:

```
int currentNumber = provider.GetCurrentNumber();
if(provider.CanPassNumber(false, currentNumber))
{
currentNumber++;
provider.SetNumber(currentNumber);
}
```

and on another thread I have something like this:

```
if(condition)
    provider.SetNumber(numberToSet);
```

Now I'm afraid that in the first function I get currentNumber which is 5, right after that on another thread the number is set to 7 and then it rewrites the 7 to 6, ignoring the change made by the thread that set it to 7.

Is there anyway to lock provider.SetNumber until the first function finishes? The critical section is basically the currentNumber which can be changed by many places in the program.

I hope I made myself clear, if not let me know and I will try to explain myself better.

EDIT:
Also I made the functions really short for the example. In reality the function is much longer and makes changes to currentNumber many times so I don't really want to put a lock around the entire function. If I lock every call to provider.SetNumber and release it after I finish it can change during the time it is released before I lock it again to call provider.SetNumber. Honestly I'm also worried about locking the entire function because of performance and deadlock.

Comment: Is the implementation of `provider` your code? (as in, code under your control)

Comment: For your edit, would need to see more of the function to see exactly what type of lock you need. As for sharing the lock across objects, make an object specifically for locking, and make it public.

Comment: I'm not looking so much for an answer to this specific case, I just read you usually lock around any writable shared field. The problem that I see is that one thread locks makes it's changes, releases the lock and then the second one, locks, makes changes releases and then the first thread locks it again to make changes but doesn't know about the changes made by the second thread and overwrites the variable. The only solution is locking an entire function and sharing the lock but performance wise that would be terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the **lock()** keywords I'd suggested seeing if you can use the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class which is designed for small operations. It's got much less overhead than lock, in fact can be down to a single CPU instruction on some CPUs.

There are a couple of methods of interest for you, [Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a.aspx) and [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx), both of which are thread safe.

Comment: +1 Interlocked is the less expensive approach, assuming his SetNumber method is simple/small.

Comment: You would still have the problem of being outside the atomic operation immediately after executing CanPassNumber

Comment: Yeah you're right I should use the interlocked class so let's say I don't just increment it, I set the value to some variable, I didn't change the OP so your answer wouldn't seem irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the [`Lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword. Also you might want to this tutorial to [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Filip said, lock is useful here.
Not only should you lock on provider.SetNumber(currentNumber), you also need to lock on any conditional that the setter depends on.

```
lock(someObject)
{
  if(provider.CanPassNumber(false, currentNumber))
  {
    currentNumber++;
    provider.SetNumber(currentNumber);
  }
}
```

as well as

```
if(condition)
{
  lock(someObject)
  {
    provider.SetNumber(numberToSet);
  }
}
```

If condition is reliant on numberToSet, you should take the lock statement around the whole block. Also note that someObject must be the *same* object.

Comment: Changed the original question to explain why I don't want to lock the entire first function (in the edit). Regarding sharing the locked object, the synch object is a private static new object, how can I share it between classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lock` statement, to enter a critical section with mutual exclusion. The `lock` will use the object's reference to differentiate one critical section from another, you must have the same reference for all your `lock` if it accesses to the same elements.

```
// Define an object which can be locked in your class.
object locker = new object();

// Add around your critical sections the following :
lock (locker) { /* ... */ }
```

That will change your code to :

```
int currentNumber = provider.GetCurrentNumber();

lock (locker)
{
  if(provider.CanPassNumber(false, currentNumber))
  {
    currentNumber++;
    provider.SetNumber(currentNumber);
  }
}
```

And :

```
if(condition)
{
  lock (locker)
  {
    provider.SetNumber(numberToSet);
  }
}
```

Comment: the lock should be in the SetNumber method or else every call to the method would have to be responsible for locking...

Comment: Depends on the way the class is designed. If it's only used with threads, then yes. Otherwise, it may be more beneficial to do it on a case-by-case basis

Comment: I changed the original question to explain why I don't want to lock the entire first function (in the edit). Regarding sharing the locked object, the synch object is a private static new object, how can I share it between classes?

Comment: Make it a public static object.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of im not so good with threading but a critical section is a part of your code that can only be accessed my one thread at a time not the other way around..

To create a critical section is easy

```
Lock(this)
{
    //Only one thread can run this at a time
}
```

note: that **this** should be replaced with some internal object...

Comment: locking "this" is generally discouraged as you should have a different object lock for each resource you want to protect - otherwise, you'll limit your instance to updating a single resource at a time...

Comment: if you look in the note text you see that i already wrote that.... it was more a simple example...

Answer (score 0):

In your SetNumber method you can simply use a lock statement:

```
public class MyProvider {
     object numberLock = new object();
     ...
     public void SetNumber(int num) {
          lock(numberLock) {
               // Do Stuff
          }
     }
}
```

Also, note that in your example `currentNumber` is a primitive (int), which means that variable's value won't be overwritten should your provider's actual data member's value change.

Comment: but let's say a consumer of this class call's set number, releases the lock, another consumer of the class locks it, set's the number and then releases, now the first one doesn't know about the changes of the second class and the problem still stands.